# Using SQL with C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm looking to make a simple username and password login program for C# and SQL, but I can't find a decent tutorial to learn SQL and how to use MS databases. Can anyone recommend a tutorial or a website to learn it? I've been looking for a few hours. Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping you have IDE (Visual Studio) installed and SQL Server Management studio you can

1. Create a C# application of your choice (Windows form or web application)
2. Add Controlls on your application that you need. (Password TextBoxes, Labels etc)
3. Create a Database on SQL Server
4. Create A Table and add desired fields to the table ( Id, UserName, Password)
5. Add Connection String to your c# application in the app.config or web.config and test connection if it succeeds
6. Add a method that connects checks the database values and the values supplied in your textbox controls

This provides a simple tutorial for windows form application as well as connecting to MS database. Give it a try
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9582c9/login-form-with-sql-in-C-Sharp/

For other simpler tutorials visit http://www.pragimtech.com